# LG Nexus 5 is not detected despite having installed LG Universal Mobile Drivers

Tags: adb, nexus-5, usb-drivers

I use Windows 8, and ADB seems to not be able to find my LG Nexus 5 (D821) despite having installed LG Universal Mobile Drivers (LGUnitedMobileDriver_S498MA22_WHQL_ML_Ver_2.2). `adb reboot bootloader` failed to find the device.

I have set the device in USB debugging mode. It does not seem that LG provides anymore anything else than the manuals on their new website.

Which USB driver should be installed to detect LG Nexus 5, and where can I download it?

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. I tried installing some other generic LG drivers which were interfering with the other drivers. (LGUnitedMobileDriver_S498MA22_WHQL_ML_Ver_2.2)

To solve this:

1. I uninstalled the generic LG drivers (LGUnitedMobileDriver_S498MA22_WHQL_ML_Ver_2.2) like a software (Control Panel -> Uninstall or Change a Program)
2. Turn on the USB Debugging
3. Unplug and replug the device
4. In the Windows Device Manager the MTP was shown with an exclamation mark
5. Open it and ask Windows to find a driver automatically which it did successfully. You will need an Internet connection
6. Should work now

Comment: In case Windows fails to find the driver automatically, download [Google USB Driver](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb) manually since Nexus (and now Pixel) serieses are considered Google devices.